# Ansible - looping over all items in a list inside a dictionary

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible to find files on Windows machines using the `win_find` module.

I'd like to do this in 2 steps:

- Find any directory in a given location (ex: find all directories under `C:/`
- Search each of those directories for a specific file (ex: `blah.cfg`)
- If a directory has said file in it, mirror its structure on a remote location (using `win_fetch`).

I managed to find directories with the example file, as well as fetching and uploading them, but for some reason I cannot find the directories first and then loop over them to search for the file.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
   - ansible.windows.win_find:
      file_type: directory
      paths: 'C:\'
      recurse: no
      get_checksum: no
    register: win_dirs
    tags: find
  - debug:
      msg: "Found directory {{ item.path }}"
    with_items: "{{ win_dirs.files }}"
    tags: find
  - ansible.windows.win_find:
      patterns: [ 'blah.cfg' ]
      file_type: file
      paths: '{{ item.path }}'
    with_items: "{{ win_dirs.files }}"
    tags: find
    register: win_apps
  - debug:
      msg: "found blah directory: {{ item.path }}"
    with_items: "{{ win_apps.files }}"
    tags: find
```

When I try using files in the `win_apps` variable, I get the following error:

```
MSG:

'dict object' has no attribute 'files'
```

To clarify, if I just search the entire root directory using recurse, this does work:

```
  - ansible.windows.win_find:
      patterns: [ 'blah.cfg' ]
      file_type: file
      paths: 'C:\'
      recurse: yes
    tags: find
    register: win_apps
  - debug:
      msg: "found blah directory: {{ item.path }}"
    with_items: "{{ win_apps.files }}"
    tags: find
```

With this method, however, I cannot mirror the directories on the remote location as they are on the host, since `win_find` traverses the subdirectories.

I think something is wrong with this bit:

```
  - ansible.windows.win_find:
      patterns: [ 'blah.cfg' ]
      file_type: file
      paths: '{{ item.path }}'
    with_items: "{{ win_dirs.files }}"
```

I've done my best to read the documentation and try other options and cannot figure this out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

The results of the second loop (`win_apps`) are inside a `results` dictionary, as outlined in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop.

So the file paths are in `{{ win_apps.results.files.path }}` - but I could not access them since `win_apps.results.files` is a list.
This has been working:

```
 - debug:
      msg: "Found file {{ item.files[1].path }}"
    loop: "{{ win_files.results }}"
```

While this has not:

```
 - debug:
      msg: "Found file {{ item.files.path }}"
    loop: "{{ win_files.results }}"
```

returning `The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'path'`

How would I be able to loop over the files and extract their paths in this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the `debug` module to look at your vars - they are probably more nested than you think. Looping and registering makes a difference